# Face to image comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-comparison

I'm trying to make a face recognition app that recognizes the person once it detects his face. i already done the face detection part but i couldn't find a way to compare the face to a photo from a photo album that is stored in the app.

Here is the face detection code:

```
-(void)markFaces:(UIImageView *)facePicture

{

// draw a CI image with the previously loaded face detection picture

CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];



// create a face detector

CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace

                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];



// create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector

NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];


for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)

{

    // get the width of the face

    CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;



    // create a UIView using the bounds of the face

    UIView* faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFeature.bounds];



    // add a border around the newly created UIView

    faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];



    // add the new view to create a box around the face

    [self.view addSubview:faceView];



    if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)

    {

        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face

        UIView* leftEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.leftEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.leftEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];

        // change the background color of the eye view

        [leftEyeView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];

        // set the position of the leftEyeView based on the face

        [leftEyeView setCenter:faceFeature.leftEyePosition];

        // round the corners

        leftEyeView.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;

        // add the view to the window

        [self.view addSubview:leftEyeView];

    }



    if(faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)

    {

        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face

        UIView* leftEye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.rightEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.rightEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];

        // change the background color of the eye view

        [leftEye setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];

        // set the position of the rightEyeView based on the face

        [leftEye setCenter:faceFeature.rightEyePosition];

        // round the corners

        leftEye.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;

        // add the new view to the window

        [self.view addSubview:leftEye];

    }



    if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)

    {

        // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face

        UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.mouthPosition.x-faceWidth*0.2, faceFeature.mouthPosition.y-faceWidth*0.2, faceWidth*0.4, faceWidth*0.4)];

        // change the background color for the mouth to green

        [mouth setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];

        // set the position of the mouthView based on the face

        [mouth setCenter:faceFeature.mouthPosition];

        // round the corners

        mouth.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.2;

        // add the new view to the window

        [self.view addSubview:mouth];

    }

}

}



-(void)faceDetector

{

// Load the picture for face detection

UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testpicture.png"]];



// Draw the face detection image

[self.view addSubview:image];



// Execute the method used to markFaces in background

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(markFaces:) withObject:image];



// flip image on y-axis to match coordinate system used by core image

[image setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];



// flip the entire window to make everything right side up

[self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];





}
```

Answer (score 1):

**From Documentation:**

> Core Image can analyze and find human faces in an image. **It performs
>   face detection, not recognition.** Face detection is the identification
>   of rectangles that contain human face features, whereas face
>   recognition is the identification of specific human faces (John, Mary,
>   and so on). After Core Image detects a face, it can provide
>   information about face features, such as eye and mouth positions. It
>   can also track the position an identified face in a video.

Unfortunately there is no api provided by apple yet to recognise the face. You might look into the [third party libraries.](https://github.com/kairosinc/Kairos-SDK-iOS)